# Save selectlist value (taxonomy) in wp and selected item

Tags: php, wordpress, taxonomy

In my admin for part i have additional fields (like price or brand - which is taxonomy). When i edit or create new part, i set up additional data.

and price saving is without any problem, but saving value from select list is something strange - it didn't save:

```
wp_set_object_terms($post_id, $_POST['part_brand'], 'brands', true);
```

according to wp doc: this function update value from taxonomy select. But for me it didn't work.

All code you could see here:

http://pastebin.com/N4gZL3uN

how to save value from select list (taxonomy) in wp?

i see that it didn't display selected value, why?

Comment: did you check the generated HTML for the drop down select menu?

Comment: @RST what did you mean? it contain all taxonomy values, but they didn't save/update.

Comment: looking at your code it seems there could be an HTML code mixup.